# Ergodicity for the mean of a linear process without finite second moment

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $\{X_k:k\in\mathbb Z\}$ is a linear process, i.e. a sequence of random variables such that
$$
X_k=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\psi_j\varepsilon_{k-j}
$$
for each $k\in\mathbb Z$, where $\{\psi_j:j\ge0\}$ is a real sequence such that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty|\psi_j|<\infty$ and $\{\varepsilon_k:k\in\mathbb Z\}$ are independent and identically distributed random variables with $\operatorname E|\varepsilon_0|<\infty$.

> Is the linear process $\{X_k:k\in\mathbb Z\}$ ergodic for the mean, i.e. does the average $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ converge almost surely (or in probability) to $\operatorname EX_0$ as $n\to\infty$?

If we assume that $\operatorname E\varepsilon_0^2<\infty$, then $\sum_{j=0}^\infty|\psi_j|<\infty$ implies the ergodicity for the mean (see p. 52 of Time Series Analysis by James D. Hamilton), but I'm interested in the case when we only assume that $\operatorname E|\varepsilon_0|<\infty$.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\mu$ the expected value of $\varepsilon_0$ and let

\begin{equation}
S_{n,j} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \varepsilon_{k-j} \quad  , \quad \bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k
\end{equation}

We have, by definition of $X_k$ :

\begin{equation}
\bar{X}_n = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_j S_{n,j} ,
\end{equation}

and thus :

\begin{equation}
|\bar{X}_n - \mathbb{E}X_0| \leq \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |\psi_j| |S_{n,j} - \mu|.
\end{equation}

Because $S_{n,j}$ satisfies the assumptions of the strong law of large numbers, we have

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}|S_{n,j} - \mu| \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{equation}

and this is true for any fixed $j$.

On the other hand, we have

$$\mathbb{E}|S_{n,j} - \mu| \leq 2 \mathbb{E}|\varepsilon_0| $$

By the discrete dominated convergence theorem we have :

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}|\bar{X}_n - \mathbb{E}X_0| \to 0
\end{equation}

thus giving the convergence in probability of the whole sequence and a.s. convergence up to a subsequence.

On a side note, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90116/how-to-show-convergence-in-probability-imply-convergence-a-s-in-this-case?lq=1) seems interesting, but the missing factor of $n$ in the sum may be a trouble.

Comment: Writing $S_n$ instead of $S_{n,j}$ was a slight abuse of notation, but it does depend on $j$, so one cannot factor it out. The answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: Indeed. As stated, this is an avatar of the dominated convergence theorem for series (hence the "discrete").

Comment: We have that for each $j\ge0$ there exists $\Omega_j\subset\Omega$ such that $\Pr(\Omega_j)=1$ and $|S_{n,j}(\omega) - \mu|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $\omega\in\Omega_j$. But does it follow that there exists $\Omega_\infty\subset\Omega$ such that $\Pr(\Omega_\infty)=1$ and $|\bar X_n(\omega) - \mathbb{E}X_0|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $\omega\in\Omega_\infty$? Could you provide some details?

Comment: For each $j \geq 0$, the set $N_j := \Omega \setminus \Omega_j$ is negligible. Thus, $N := \bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty} N_j$ is also negligible (basic measure theory). But outside $N$ (that is, we set $\Omega_{\infty} := \Omega \setminus N$), we have pointwise convergence _everywhere_ of $|S_{n,j}(\omega) - \mu|$ to $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and your comments! I'm still not sure how we can justify the interchange of the limits (I deleted my previous comments about the interchange of limits). If we want to use the dominated convergence theorem for series, we need to find a sequence of random variables $\{d_j:j\ge0\}$ such that $|\psi_j||S_{n,j}-\mu|\le d_j$ for each $n\ge1$ and $\sum_{j=0}^\infty d_j$ converges almost surely, right? How can we find such a sequence? Or is there another way to justify the interchange of the limits?

Comment: I would do it the following way : pick any realization $\omega$ in your nice set $\Omega_{\infty}$ (harmless since it has full measure) and consider the _real series_ $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |\psi_j| |S_{n,j}(\omega) - \mu|$. Because $\omega$ lies in $\Omega_{\infty}$, for any $j \geq 0$, $|S_{n,j}(\omega) - \mu| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. By DCT for real series (we only have numbers now), the full series also converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. This being true for any $\omega \in \Omega_{\infty}$, the a.s. convergence follows.

Comment: $|S_{n,j}(\omega)-\mu|$ is a bounded sequence since it converges as $n\to\infty$, but the bound depends on $j$. We have that $|S_{n,j}(\omega)-\mu|\le c_j(\omega)$. Hence, we need to prove that the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty|\psi_j|c_j(\omega)$ converges in order to use the DCT. How can we do that?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{E} | \varepsilon_0 |$ was assumed to be finite, the desired convergence holds almost surely.

Comment: We still need to prove that the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty|\psi_j|c_j(\omega)$ converges. We basically need to prove that the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty|\psi_j|\sup_{n\ge1}|S_{n,j}-\mu|$ converges almost surely. Then we will be able to use the DCT.

Comment: Okay, I admit there was a flaw in the proof, but here is a definitive fix to it. [Here](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEQQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783642393624-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1406311-p175305834&ei=X5e_VKDJBJXdate4giA&usg=AFQjCNE7ZRR7DF1OOBHlkpCDJp9Vi2FzJQ), from page 18 on, the author uses martingales to show that actually, the strong law of large numbers holds in $L^1$, that is, $\mathbb{E}| S_{n,j} - \mu | \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: But we also have $\mathbb{E}|S_{n,j} - \mu| \leq 2 \mathbb{E}|\epsilon_0|$, which entails, by the DCT, the convergence of your original mean in $L^1$. In particular, convergence also holds a.s. And sorry for the wrongness of the first attempts.

Comment: No need to be sorry, thank you for your time. Indeed $\bar X_n\to\operatorname E X_0$ in $L^1$ as $n\to\infty$, but how does almost sure convergence also hold? Convergence in $L^1$ does not imply almost sure convergence in general.

Comment: That means that I am _very_ rusty on probabilities. Almost sure convergence holds up to a subsequence, but at least you recover convergence in probability.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the last corrections. Also, you don't need to unaccept each time you have another question, for the problem is interesting enough in itself to draw me in, even without any material gain. :)